# Find the Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm currently studying the product rule and have come across a section of questions that seems to make no sense. I'm sure there's just one little thing that I'm missing but I am unable to spot it. Anyhow, I was hoping someone could show me step-by-step how to solve the following, and hopefully I can get the rest:

Differentiate $(x^2 - 1)(x^3 - 1)$. You may need both the chain rule and the product rule

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\textbf{hint:}
$

if you require the derivative with respect to x

then use

$$
\frac{d}{dx}u(x)v(x) = \frac{du}{dx}v + u\frac{dv}{dx}
$$
using

$$
u = x^2-1,\\
v = x^3-1.
$$

take the derivatives of the functions first and plug in and then simplify.

the result is

$$
2x\left(x^3-1\right) + \left(x^2-1\right)3x^2 = 5x^4-3x^2-2x 
$$

taking the result
$$
5x^4-3x^2-2x  = x\left(5x^3-3x-2\right)
$$
I know that there is a root x = 1 using reminder theorem. therefore I know I can write the equation as

$$
5x^4-3x^2-2x = x(x-1)P(x)
$$

use long division to get P(x)?

Comment: I have up to that point and i get to 2x*(x^3-1) + (x^2-1).3x^2 but no matter which way i try the simplifying whether multiplying first and then simplyifiying or the reverse i never seem to get the answer

Comment: What is the book answer?

Comment: x(x-1)(5x^2 + 5x + 2)

Comment: @Paul have you come across algebraic division?

Comment: Yes, and i see where you'd add that in, it's incredible how simple something is once you know the answer. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to go head on with simple problems like these:
 $$\frac{d}{dx} [(x^2 - 1)(x^3 - 1)] \\
=  \frac{d}{dx} (x^5 - x^2 -x^3 + 1)\\
= \frac{d}{dx} (x^5) - \frac{d}{dx} (x^2) -\frac{d}{dx}(x^3) + \frac{d}{dx}(1)\\
= 5x^{5-1} - 2x^{2-1} - 3x^{3-1} + 0\\
= 5x^4 - 3x^2 - 2x\\
= x(5x^3 - 3x -2)\\
= x(x-1)(5x^2 + 5x + 2)$$